# Adding elements to a list using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, function, for-loop

I have code in which I specify the dimensions of a matrix, and up to 5x5 matrix it will get the positions of each element in the matrix mapped. So far this works for 5 rows and 5 columns, named U, Lf, Ls, I and R. However I want to find a way of automating this to have minimal human interaction so that I can specify a matrix that is in multiples of 5 (so for example give it a 10x10 or 15x15 matrix) and it will automatically add new elements to `row_labels` and `col_labels`, with names like `U_1, Lf_1, Ls_1, I_1, R_1` and then `U_2, Lf_2`... for the next set and so on and so forth.

I am racking my brain on how an automation for this would work all I know is I need to use a for loop of some kind? How would this be implemented?

```
def get_addresses(i,j):
    # Create the matrix
    matrix = np.zeros((i,j))
    
    # Define the row and column labels
    row_labels = ['U', 'Lf', 'Ls', 'I', 'R']
    col_labels = ['U', 'Lf', 'Ls', 'I', 'R']
    
    # Create a dictionary to map labels to indices
    #the keys are tuples of row and column labels
    #the values are tuples of row and column indices
    #first element of the tuple represents the row index
    #second element represents the column index
    index_map = {(row_labels[i], col_labels[j]): (i, j) for i in range(matrix.shape[0]) for j in range(matrix.shape[1])}
    
    return index_map
```

EDIT
If i nest your solution within what I have above:

```
def get_addresses(i,j):
    # Create the matrix
    matrix = np.zeros((i,j))

    def make_rl(n):
        row_labels_base = ['U', 'Lf', 'Ls', 'I', 'R']
        row_labels = row_labels_base[:]
        col_labels = row_labels_base[:]
        for i in range((n-1)):
            row_labels += ["%s%d" % (lbl,i+1) for lbl in row_labels_base]
            col_labels += ["%s%d" % (lbl,i+1) for lbl in row_labels_base]
        return row_labels, col_labels

    
    # Create a dictionary to map labels to indices
    #the keys are tuples of row and column labels
    #the values are tuples of row and column indices
    #first element of the tuple represents the row index
    #second element represents the column index
    index_map = {(row_labels[i], col_labels[j]): (i, j) for i in range(matrix.shape[0]) for j in range(matrix.shape[1])}
    
    return index_map
```

how would I define `n` when calling overall function?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to populate `row_labels` and `col_labels` based on... something?

Comment: yes, populate them with new terms that are those in the original lists but with 1, 2 or 3 added on the end depending on how many iterations of those lists there are

Comment: How would you determine "how many iterations of those lists there are"?

Comment: I am thinking it would be an input of that function. so because lets say its in multiples of 5 (no. of elements in list), i enter 2, so it gives 10x10 matrix. first 5 elements are U, Lf, Ls, I, R and then we have U_1, Lf_1, Ls_1, I_1, R_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will yield the list of row labels given a matrix dimension of `n`:

```
def make_rl(n):
    row_labels_base = ['U', 'Lf', 'Ls', 'I', 'R']
    row_labels = row_labels_base[:]
    for i in range((n-1)//5):
        row_labels += ["%s%d" % (lbl,i+1) for lbl in row_labels_base]
    return row_labels
```

Comment: for the columns then should I just add `col_labels_base = ['U', 'Lf', 'Ls', 'I', 'R']
    col_labels = row_labels_base[:]` in there?

Comment: Actually, you could use it to generate column labels as-is.

Comment: this is very interesting, thanks for this. please see my edit for one final comment.